# What name to give to objects when adding to ArrayList

Tags: java, object, arraylist

I have a container class with an array list defined for a Person object.

The person who is using the program is asked to register a person and I have to create the object Person, give it the name, lastname and age the user inputed and after that add it to the ArrayList.

My question is, when creating the Person object, can I give the same name to every object I add? Or do I have to name them person1, person2, etc?

If so, how?

Thanks

Comment: I dont really get why am I getting downvoted. Is this not a worth it question?

Comment: Answer to this question you can read at all books about Java. You getting downvoted because asked question about basics. It's not unique problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't have to give them different names. Doing so would actually defeat the purpose of using a collection. You can just do the following:

```
Person p = new Person(...);
// set name, age, etc.
list.add(p);
```

Each time you do that, a new `Person` is created and added to the list. Think of the name `p` as just a temporary variable that can be discarded.

Comment: Let me see if I understood. When I create the first person, and object named p will be added to my ArrayList. When entering the second person, another object named p (with different name,age,lastname) will be added to the same ArrayList. How does the ArrayList internally copes with having several objects with the same name?

Comment: @TiraULTI The ArrayList doesn't keep the name `p`, it creates its own internally each time you add a new object.

Answer (score 0):

You don't work with names, you work with links to memory. When you create an object, for example, use **new** operator, you are getting a link to memory part where stored data of object.

If you write

```
Person p = new Person()    
list.add(p)
p = new Person()    
list.add(p)
```

You save to array 2 links to different object.